# Circular crossword

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

After solving the following crossword, you'll find five letters that stand out from the rest.  Combine them to find the solution to this puzzle.  Hint: it's something you'll need to succeed at this.

[image]

<sup>1.  Word with wear, take, or stand

2.  Roast lightly

3.  Cocktail with cognac and orange liqueur

4.  Acceleration unit

5.  Island off Newfoundland's Avalon Peninsula

6.  Catch some rays

7.  Part of a plot

8.  Word with tape or symbol

9.  In short supply

10. Capital ____

11. Measures of petrol

12. Storage devices

13. Cancel out

14. Casino pastime

15. Steal

16. Top up

17. Paved area

18. Went to bed

19. Up to the task

20. Sharp blows

21. Cultivation

22. Climber's challenge</sup>

Comment: Total guess but maybe the final answer is logic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Filled out:

> [image]

In the clockwise direction, starting with the 1, the letters are:

> <sup>1</sup>UNDER **I** <sup>17</sup>TERRACE <sup>12</sup>DISKS <sup>19</sup>ABLE <sup>4</sup>GAL <sup>11</sup>LITRES <sup>20</sup>RAPS **S** <sup>2</sup>PARCH <sup>22</sup>CLIFF **L** <sup>7</sup>ACRE **K** <sup>10</sup>CITY <sup>16</sup>FILL

In the counterclockwise direction starting at 3, they are:

> <sup>3</sup>SIDECAR <sup>18</sup>RETIRED <sup>13</sup>NULLIFY <sup>8</sup>TICKER <sup>5</sup>CALF <sup>15</sup>FILCH <sup>14</sup>CRAPS <sup>9</sup>SPARSER <sup>21</sup>TILLAGE **L** <sup>6</sup>BASK

The five extra letters spell:

> SKILL

Comment: Or alternatively I suppose you could murder people until somebody gives you the answer...  (Rearranging the letters a bit)

Answer (score 2):

The answers to the clues are:

> (> indicates clockwise, < is counter-clockwise)
>  1 UNDER >
>  2 PARCH >
>  3 SIDECAR <
>  4 G
>  5 CALF <
>  6 BASK <
>  7 ACRE >
>  8 TICKER <
>  9 SPARSE <
>  10 CITY >
>  11 LITRES >
>  12 DISKS >
>  13 NULLIFY <
>  14 CRAPS <
>  15 FILCH <
>  16 FILL >
>  17 TERRACE >
>  18 RETIRED <
>  19 ABLE >
>  20 RAPS >
>  21 TILLAGE <
>  22 CLIFF >

What stood out to me is:

> There are 5 sets of double letters: L, R, L, S, and F.  Not sure what to do with them though.